# getting Error as 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent' in my node.js service

Tags: node.js, express, ldapjs

Below is my code,

```
app.get("/getList", function (req, resp) {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    var client = ldap.createClient({
        url: 'ldap://my_ip:389'
    });

    client.bind('cn=pratik', 'pratik', function (err) {
        return resp.send(err);
    });

    var opts = {
        filter: '(objectclass=classToSearch)',
        scope: 'sub',
        attributes: ['ipaddress']
      };
      var entries= {};
      var i=0;
      client.search('o=a', opts, function(err, res) {


        res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
          console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
            oxe[i] = entry.object;
            i++;
        });
        res.on('end', function(result) {
            console.log("pratik");
            console.log(entries);
            return resp.send(entries);
          });
});
```

Here when I print the entries, it shows correct result but it doesn't send the response. I can see error as 'Error: Can't set headers after they are sent'. below is the complete Error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:357
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you call `resp.send` twice: in the `client.bind` callback and in the `res.on("end")` callback.

I'd suggest putting the second job inside of the `bind` callback, so that you can check the error, and if there is one, you stop there.

If that succeeds, then I will send the `entries`.

```
app.get("/getList", function(req, resp) {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
  var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://my_ip:389'
  });

  client.bind('cn=pratik', 'pratik', function(err) {
    if (err) return resp.send(err);
    var opts = {
      filter: '(objectclass=classToSearch)',
      scope: 'sub',
      attributes: ['ipaddress']
    };
    var entries = {};
    var i = 0;
    client.search('o=a', opts, function(err, res) {
      res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
        console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
        oxe[i] = entry.object;
        i++;
      });
      res.on('end', function(result) {
        console.log("pratik");
        console.log(entries);
        return resp.send(entries);
      });
    });
  });
});
```